# Is it possible to implement a DLL concept in Android app development without using JNI?

Tags: android, dll, jar, java-native-interface

I have an android application which uses a .jar file for executing. The jar file is added to the project while building. So the final output is just an apk. This is good. But I found difficulty in continuous building the project even if there is only change in the jar file. How to separate the jar from the project and make it accessible at run time only (just like DLL), without using JNI? So that there is no need to build the app each time the jar changes.

Answer (score 0):

This one looks like the way to go. DexClassLoader:

http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html

It is "just" a ClassLoader, with everything that comes with the territory.

PS. (Unsolicited advice ahead!) That may not be what you actually need. I would consider why the way your projects are currently built is inconvenient and optimize that first.